# Оператор "-" и "<" невозможно применить к операнду типа "int" и "char[]"

Tags: c#

```
int n = 11;
char[] syb = new char[n];
int b = 'a';
             
for (int i = 0; i < syb; i++)
{
    b = b + 2;
    Console.Write(syb[i] + "\t");
}


for (int i = syb -1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    Console.Write(syb[i] + "\t");
}
```

Comment: `i < syb.Length`

Comment: точно ,спасибо ))

Comment: во втором цикле то же самое

Comment: понял . Только теперь прога не запускается .Пишу в конце ещё Сonsole.Write();} и пишут ошибку :
Ошибка CS1501 Ни одна из перегрузок метода "Write" не принимает 0 аргументов

Comment: `Сonsole.WriteLine();`?

Comment: нам так сказали прогу заканчивать тип без этого не так

Comment: Брать учебник, учить шарп. Я не смогу ответить здесь вам на все возникающие у вас вопросы. Если у вас возник новый вопрос, а текущий решен - поставьте галку ответу ниже и задайте новый вопрос отдельно, изложив в нем максимум деталей о вашей новой проблеме.

Comment: [Здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.console.write?view=netframework-4.8) вы можете почитать про все перегрузки метода Console.Write. Как видите, у него нет перегрузок с 0 аргументов.

Comment: @МаксимФисман `Write` нельзя 0 аргументов `WriteLine` можно, не путайтесь. А почему - а потому что что должен сделать `Write` с 0 аргументов? Очевидно, ничего, вот его поэтому и нет.

Comment: @aepot Пора короче идти спать... Схожу с ума

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно нельзя, ведь int - это число, в то время как char - это просто одиночный символ, типа 'a', '5', '&' и т.д.

Если вы хотите получить длину вашего массива syb, вам следует свойство [Length](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.array.length?view=netframework-4.8):

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < syb.Length; i++)
...
for (int i = syb.Length -1; i >= 0; i--)
...
```

Length - это `общее число элементов во всех измерениях массива Array; ноль, если в массиве нет элементов`

Comment: Вы правы. Это к вопросу о том, как разработчики языков выбирают функцию для получения размера массива: [image](http://img0.reactor.cc/pics/post/full/it-%D1%8E%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80-geek-4857528.jpeg) 